# Leaflet.js: detecting when map finishes zooming

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, leaflet

So I'm making this application with leafet.js.

This application requires that I have to manually draw grids onto the screen,
that I've taken care in a `draw_grid()` function that draws a bunch of polygons to the screen.

I have this function that I'm calling to trigger the change of the leaflet map.

`zoom` - the zoom integer and `size` is a dict like `{x:1,y:1}` that controls the size of the tiles drawn onto the map. (they need to change as the units the tiles are being drawn under are lat,long points on the map.

```
function changeZoom(zoom,size){
    map.setZoom(zoom); 
    setSize(size);   
    setTimeout(drawGrid,500)s;
}
```

The reason I have to use the `setTimeout` is because the leaflet *ignores* any drawing commands onto the map (which I'm doing as a layer) until the map has finished animating.

How to do this asynchronously instead?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the `map.zoomend` event, described in the API [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend)

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    drawGrid();
});
```

Once the map finishes the zooming animation, it will then call the `drawGrid` function.

Comment: This event still seems to fire for me many times during a "scroll-in zoom". Is it because I'm using a touchpad?

Comment: is there a way to check for multiple events like "paning" as well as "zooming" ? also i checked that "load" event is not getting fired.

Comment: @SamSelikoff seems not to be related to  touchpad. Also happens by mousewheel, if not scrolled supersuperfast. Couldn't find any debounce option either. Thus, thus logic needs to be implemented manually.

Answer (score 19):

In newer version of Leaflet, "`zoomed`" is no longer an event. There are now "`zoomstart`" and "`zoomend`" events:

```
map.on("zoomstart", function (e) { console.log("ZOOMSTART", e); });
map.on("zoomend", function (e) { console.log("ZOOMEND", e); });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is best way to managed leflet Zoom control clicked

```
    /*Zoom Control Click Managed*/
    var bZoomControlClick = false;
    mymap.on('zoomend',function(e){
        var currZoom = mymap.getZoom();
        if(bZoomControlClick){
            console.log("Clicked "+currZoom);
        }
        bZoomControlClick = false;
    });     
    var element = document.querySelector('a.leaflet-control-zoom-in');
    L.DomEvent.addListener(element, 'click', function (e) {
        bZoomControlClick = true;
        $(mymap).trigger("zoomend");
    });
    var element1 = document.querySelector('a.leaflet-control-zoom-out');
    L.DomEvent.addListener(element1, 'click', function (e) {
        bZoomControlClick = true;
        $(mymap).trigger("zoomend");
    });
```